# How to create a conditional column in Python that picks data from different column based on the year?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataset looks something like this:

| Product ID | Sales Year | Sales_percentage_2016 | Sales_percentage_2017 | Sales_percentage_2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016 | 5 | 8 | 5 |
| 2 | 2017 | 7 | 9 | 6 |

Output should be something like this:

| Product ID | Sales Year | Sales_Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016 | 5 |
| 2 | 2017 | 9 |

So that this was unwanted data can be removed and relevant can be kept.

Comment: I cannot find any `condition` in your question, - looks like you want simply select few columns

Comment: Read about select columns using loc and iloc. Regards.

Comment: @NoobVB sales year contains year information. Need sales percentage information from that year alone in that row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+column+conditional

Comment: Can we assume that in the row which contains "Product ID" = 1, "Sales Year" = 2017, we will find same values as above for year 2017 (8) and 2018 (5)?

Comment: @PaulH it's not a simple conditional ;)

Comment: @A259 I closed it b/c as presented, this could be solved with `numpy.select` or unstacking the data frame & manipulating the column names. There are *so many* questions and answers on all of those topics

Comment: @A259 to be fair, there are **so many** "*I have this, I want this*" questions, with little or no research, most of them being on the same 3-4 topics, it's quite easy to close... Here it could indeed be solved with melting and filtering (although not so efficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
# get Year to use for indexing
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['Sales Year'])
# add prefix
cols = 'Sales_percentage_' + cols.astype(str)
# index
df['Sales'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
# get rid of unnecessary columns
df = df.filter(regex=r'^(?!Sales_percentage_)')
```

output:

```
   Product ID  Sales Year  Sales
0           1        2016      5
1           2        2017      9
```